# Automating git commands in Windows

Tags: bash, batch-file, github, ssh, build-automation

Context: I am building an automated build script which will run on a Windows server box (necessary because our development software package is windows only). My client box is also Windows. It should execute a number of steps, one of which is to login to github, discard all local changes (just in case; there really shouldn't be any local changes), fetch and merge.

Restrictions: 
1) I should be able to run one batch file (or other script file, as long as it runs on a windows box)
2) I cannot walk over to the box and input my password for SSH everytime. It should work automatically.

Problem: I cannot get Git and SSH to work nicely with my Windows batch file.

My First Attempt:

```
:: set repo folder
CD %2

:: check status
CALL git status
ECHO.

:: discard all changes
ECHO ~  discard all changes
ECHO.
CALL git reset --hard
CALL git clean -f -d
ECHO.

:: switch branch
ECHO ~  checkout branch %4
ECHO.
CALL git checkout %4
ECHO.

:: get any changes from server
ECHO ~  fetch %3
ECHO.
CALL git fetch %3
ECHO.

:: merge changes into current branch
ECHO ~  merge %3/%4
ECHO.
CALL git merge %3/%4
ECHO.
```

The parameter %2 is the windows file location, %3 is the github HTTPS url, %4 is the branch name.

This works, but uses HTTPS, which means entering my username and password manually.

So I tried doing it in SSH (via bash), using the commands:

```
eval `ssh-agent`
ssh-add /z/id_rsa
```

like so from batch:

```
CD C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\
sh.exe --login -i -c "eval `ssh-agent` && ssh-add /z/id_rsa && exit"
```

However, SSH also requires me to enter the key passphrase every time I use this command.

How can I, either A) keep the SSH login information live between batch/bash scripts or B) enter the passphrase programmatically?

Comment: Is your client running Windows or Linux?

Comment: Ansgar Wiechers: Windows, both on client and (not yet existing) server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using Windows on client and server I'd recommend using [`plink`](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/x86/plink.exe) from the [PuTTY Suite](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) for automating stuff.

The suite also includes an SSH agent (`pageant`). However, you only need an agent if the private key is password protected. For automation purposes I'd create a dedicated keypair without a passphrase and use that key:

```
plink -ssh -batch -i "C:\path\to\private.ppk" user@host C:\serverpath\batch.cmd
```

In the above command `C:\serverpath\batch.cmd` is the location of the batch file on the server. You can also keep the commands you want to run in a file on the client and use that with `plink`:

```
plink -ssh -batch -i "C:\path\to\private.ppk" -m C:\localpath\batch.cmd user@host
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks Ansgar. Once I regenerated my key without a passphrase, the original script I wrote worked almost verbatim, the only difference being I passed all the git commands to sh.exe. I will however take a look at using Putty's plink, maybe I can clean up the chain of commands into something readable for others on my team.